# Majorana Fermions and the Divergence of Currents

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions, grassmann-numbers

I am working on exercise 3.4d in Peskin and Schroeder's *Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*. In part c I found the Dirac Lagrangian density to be $$L = i\chi_1^\dagger \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \chi_1 + i\chi_2^\dagger \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \chi_2 + im(\chi_2^T \sigma_2 \chi_1 - \chi_1^\dagger \sigma_2 \chi_2^*).$$ In order to show that the current density $$J^\mu = \chi_1^\dagger\bar{\sigma}^\mu\chi_1 - \chi_2^\dagger\bar{\sigma}^\mu\chi_2$$ is divergenceless. I am trying to compute the equations of motion. I know that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \chi_2^\dagger} = 0$ from Euler Lagrange. The solutions manual says that the corresponding equations of motion should be $i \bar{\sigma}^\mu \partial_\mu \chi_2 - im\sigma_2 \chi_1^* = 0$. I was able to get the first term, but I am having trouble getting the second term. Now I noticed that if I treat the $\chi_i$ as a two component vector of Grassmann numbers, i.e. $(\chi_{ia}, \chi_{ib})^T$ I was able to show that $\chi_2^T \sigma_2 \chi_1 = (\chi_2^\dagger \sigma_2 \chi_1^*)^*$.

**First Question: Is it correct to treat $\chi_i$ as a 2 component vector of Grassmann numbers?** I noticed that in the problem statement, the authors treated $\chi_a(x)$, for $a = 1,2$ as Grassmann numbers, so I initially thought that the $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ introduced in part c and onwards were just Grassmann numbers. However, in the solutions manual I noticed that in parts c and d, there are transposes of $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$. This suggested to me that these $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are vectors of grassmann numbers. Which interpretation is correct, the vector of grassmann numbers or just plain old grassmann numbers?

**Second question: Assuming that $\chi_2^T \sigma_2 \chi_1 = (\chi_2^\dagger \sigma_2 \chi_1^*)^*$ is correct, I noticed that if I say $\frac{\partial}{\partial \chi_2^\dagger}(\chi_2^\dagger \sigma_2 \chi_1^*)^* = - \sigma_2 \chi_1^*$, I get the correct equations of motion; Why is this correct? Can anyone show me why $\frac{\partial}{\partial \chi_2^\dagger}(\chi_2^\dagger \sigma_2 \chi_1^*)^* = - \sigma_2 \chi_1^*$ is true?**

Next I noticed that if I blindly assume the equations of motion to be true, I see that the divergence of the current is proportional to $\chi_2^T \sigma_2 \chi_1 + \chi_1^\dagger \sigma_2 \chi_2^* - \chi_1^T\sigma_2\chi_2 - \chi_2^\dagger \sigma_2 \chi_1^*$. The author claims this is 0. **Third question: Why is true? One thing I noticed is that if I treat these to be real than I get 0, but I not sure why can treat these to be real. Can anyone explain?**

Comment: Doesn't Majorana morally mean you can drop $*$ and change $\dagger$ to $T$?

Comment: @ConnorBehan I am not too sure. Is there a way I can show your claims are true?

Comment: Yes. By looking up the definition of Majorana fermion.

Comment: @ConnorBehan What about the first question? Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Oh, yes. The original Dirac spinor had 4 components so $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ have two each.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you!!!